# Why adding numbers in using transformation table

Tags: r

I have the following table (dat2) which is a transformation table:

```
> dat2 <- read.table(file.choose(), head=T, as.is=T)       #### Transformation table
> head (dat2)
                                    items newitem
1 EE945098C667EAE169914A85B2694508 SELECT     OV1
2 23552A46AA353DD331B6B6DD7A83DA8C SELECT     OV2
3 63B31CA67BB356B0965E19E7F66B3F11 SELECT     OV3
4 38A43F4165420E2F12EE500DC7E0E67C SELECT     OV4
5 ECEAFE485E65C9851907DEED13D4E9E7 SELECT     OV5
6 85190C0EFB3B7450568D84B3B3E3DB91 SELECT     OV6
```

I have the input table (dat1):

```
> head (dat1)
   sequence    support
1   <{OV1}> 0.14519496
2 <{OV195}> 0.09071318
3 <{OV196}> 0.09125194
4 <{OV197}> 0.09785171
5 <{OV198}> 0.09812109
6 <{OV304}> 0.09886188
```

I use the following to transform between the table. I mean that each OV will be replaced by its equivalent string:

```
> for (i in 1:nrow(dat2)) {
+   dat1$sequence <- gsub(dat2$newitem[i], dat2$items[i], dat1$sequence)
+ }
```

I get for each dat1sequence an additional number as can be seen from the second line SELECT95, SELECT96 etc. while it should be SELECT only. Why I get it? and how can I avoid of getting it?

```
> head (dat1)
                                       sequence    support
1   <{EE945098C667EAE169914A85B2694508 SELECT}> 0.14519496
2 <{EE945098C667EAE169914A85B2694508 SELECT95}> 0.09071318
3 <{EE945098C667EAE169914A85B2694508 SELECT96}> 0.09125194
4 <{EE945098C667EAE169914A85B2694508 SELECT97}> 0.09785171
5 <{EE945098C667EAE169914A85B2694508 SELECT98}> 0.09812109
6 <{63B31CA67BB356B0965E19E7F66B3F11 SELECT04}> 0.09886188
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `"\\d*"` to your pattern. It will capture the extra numbers  and eliminate them for the replacement.

```
sub(paste0(newitem, "\\d*"), items, sequence)
#[1] "<{EE945098C667EAE169914A85B2694508 SELECT}>"
```

**Data**

```
items <- "EE945098C667EAE169914A85B2694508 SELECT"
newitem <- "OV1"
sequence <- "<{OV195}>"
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre. Can you please tell me where to change it? Is this the required change in the loop:
for (i in 1:nrow(dat2)) {

  dat3$sequence <- sub(paste0(dat2$newitem[i], "\\d*"), dat2$items[i], dat3$sequence)
}

Comment: Hi Pierre, I get wrong results using the following loop: for (i in 1:nrow(dat2)) { dat3$sequence <-sub(paste0(dat2$newitem[i], "\\d*"), dat2$items[i], dat3$sequence) } 
The result for: "1" "<{OV144}>" 0.0754101809002945
"2" "<{OV145}>" 0.0708876735380732
"3" "<{OV146}>" 0.073832562053008
is: "1" "<{FBBF27370FD0553FAC64E36E95A61E50 EXECUTE PROCEDURE}>" 0.227701005025126
"2" "<{FBBF27370FD0553FAC64E36E95A61E50 EXECUTE PROCEDURE}>" 0.286903266331658
"3" "<{FBBF27370FD0553FAC64E36E95A61E50 EXECUTE PROCEDURE}>" 0.121309673366834
Why is it?

Comment: I cant tell from the comment what is happening. Please add to your question.